# Particle motion along a circle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There exists a particle which moves with constant speed 5 unit/sec along a circular path of radius 3 units which is centered at the origin in the plane given by the equation 2x+2y+z = 0. Calculate the velocity vector v and the acceleration vector a as the particle moves through the point P(1, −2, 2).

Shouldn't acceleration be a 0 vector? And as for velocity I think it should be
5(2i+2j+k) at all points. Am I correct?

Comment: The acceleration vector is not zero. The speed may not be changing, but the direction of the velocity is. Zero acceleration would imply motion along a straight line.

Comment: The velocity vector you indicate would have the particle moving at a right angle to the plane rather than in the plane.

Comment: Velocity vector will not be perpendicular to plane

Comment: I think acceleration vector should be -i+2j-2k as it will be directed towards origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The velocity component cannot be the same throughout otherwise it wouldn't move along a circle. It would move along a straight line.

The velocity vector is perpendicular to the line joining the center of the circle to that point. Furthermore it is perpendicular to the perpendicular to the plane since the velocity component lies on the plane.

Since it has not been mentioned if it is moving clockwise or anticlockwise I'm assuming one of the directions,

$$\hat{v} = \frac{(2 \hat{i}+2\hat{j}+\hat{k})\times (\hat{i}-2\hat{j}+2\hat{k})}{|(2 \hat{i}+2\hat{j}+\hat{k})\times (\hat{i}-2\hat{j}+2\hat{k})|}=\frac{6\hat{i}-3\hat{j}-6\hat{k}}{9}$$
$$\vec{v}=|v|\cdot \hat{v}= 5\cdot \frac{6\hat{i}-3\hat{j}-6\hat{k}}{9}$$

Acceleration is caused due to the centripetal force,

$$\vec{a} = \frac{v^2}{r} (-\hat{n})= \frac{5}{3}(-\hat{i}+2\hat{j}-2\hat{k})$$